# Getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'" error on aws ec2 ubuntu. I already installed the beautifulSoup4

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I am creating a django web app, and i am trying to use beautifulsoap4 for web scraping.
when i try running the application using `python3 manage.py runserver` command, i get this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
I have already installed the beautifulsoap module. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of many reasons,
Here are a few:

1. You didn't install it properly
2. You use a non-local environment and didn't install it on the env.
3. You didn't use the right interpreter
4. Check spelling of the install line. You wrote beautifulsoap instead of beautifulsoup .

There are many other possibilities, if none of this assists- add more information to your question.

You may try to reinstall the package and restart your virtual env (or env)